# updating date to null

Tags: sql, oracle, null, sql-update

I am trying to update a enroll_date row to null and it is telling me `"cannot update (%s) to NULL"`, so I tried doing putting `TO_CHAR`and it still doesn't help...

enroll_date shows this which I want to make it to null

```
ENROLL_DATE 
07-FEB-07
```

This is what I have

```
UPDATE ENROLLMENT
SET TO_CHAR(ENROLL_DATE) = NULL
WHERE STUDENT_ID ='125'
      AND SECTION_ID ='61';
```

how can I set enroll_date to null ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears to be telling you that your data model defines `enroll_date` as a `NOT NULL` column.  You cannot, therefore, set it to be NULL.

You could modify the table definition to allow NULL values

```
ALTER TABLE enrollment
  MODIFY( enroll_date DATE NULL )
```

It seems likely, however, that this was an intentional choice made when defining the data model that should not be altered.  I don't see how it would make sense to have an `enrollment` without having an `enroll_date`.

Answer (score 9):

Remove the TO_CHAR function. You're updating a column, not the function'd value

```
UPDATE ENROLLMENT
SET ENROLL_DATE = NULL
WHERE STUDENT_ID ='125'
      AND SECTION_ID ='61';
```

Comment: I have already tried it, and it is telling me 01407. 00000 -  "cannot update (%s) to NULL"

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE ENROLLMENT
SET ENROLL_DATE = NULL
WHERE STUDENT_ID ='125'
      AND SECTION_ID ='61';
```

If this does not work,you probably have the column definition NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

use ALTER COLUMN instead of MODIFY

```
ALTER TABLE enrollment<br/>
ALTER COLUMN enroll_date DATE NULL
```